# Flipping function return with print

Tags: python, printing, return

probably I am gessing not properly but I can't figure out why that happen.

A break through the script I am trying to write, OS Windows 10, Visual Studio Code, Python 3.7

I wrote a class with a function which should print out into the console and in a .txt file some data scraped by a web page.

Here the function:

```
def create_alimento(Componenti_principali):  
    for col1, col2 in zip(soup.select('#tblComponenti > tr.testonormale > td:nth-of-type(1)'), soup.select('#tblComponenti > tr.testonormale > td:nth-of-type(2)')):
        print('{: <70} {}'.format(col1.text, col2.text))
```

The console's output doesn't have any problem, it does it's own job and seems all clear to me. 
What I don't understand is the .txt output, it comes to an error, TypeError precisely: write() argument must be str, not None.

It clearly say that the Class I am trying to print (which include also the function above) is a None type, therefore is the main object.

Now, the thing is, if I flip:

```
print('{: <70} {}'.format(col1.text, col2.text))
```

with :

```
return('{: <70} {}'.format(col1.text, col2.text))
```

...the function object type is "string", not anymore NoneType.

I wouldn't point it out if all would be ok, obviously, using **`return`** instead of **`print`**, doesn't give a .txt output.

Anybody does know what happen here? and any advice to print both at console and in a .txt the same output?

Thanks in advance,
Mx

Comment: You haven't shown any code that writes to a file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 
Hi Daniel, do you want me to write you the entire code? Or just what is supposed to be the output ?

> a = create_alimento(Componenti_principali)
print(a)

with open("pippo.txt", "w") as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(a)
    txt_file.close()

Comment: No but you have to explain what you are doing and what is supposed to happen. And why does it surprise you that return returns something and print doesn't?

Comment: @DanielRoseman
I am trying to print both, console view and into a .txt (the same output). 
The idea with this script is to scrap a table value from a web page, which has hundreds and hundreds of values. It is suppose to receive an output with two columns of data (correspondenting to the first two <td> value of the table velues.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 
The thing is that if I use return, the type object is a string (which is ok for the console print) but it doesn't give me the .txt output. 
If I use print and debugging the script I have the TypeError, write() argument must be a str, not None. 

I don't understand why if I flip print with return the function's object change the type and furthermore I can't print the same output at console and into a .txt file.

That is the question

Comment: So why can't you both print and return it? Or, better, print it in the code that writes to your file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It should print it in the console and the .txt file (same output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `return` returns a value from a function, for example:

```
def f():
    return 7

seven = f()
# value of seven is now 7
```

A print does not return a value, for example:

```
def f():
    print(7)  # at this point "7" is printed to the standard output

seven = f()
# value of seven is now None
```

If you want to both print a value and return a value, you should do exactly that, e.g.:

```
def f():
    print(7)  # at this point "7" is printed to the standard output
    return 7

seven = f()
# value of seven is now 7
```

BTW, It would be a better design to just return the value. You can always print it from the outside if you want, i.e.:

```
def f():
    return 7

seven = f()
# value of seven is now 7
print(seven)  # at this point "7" is printed to the standard output
```

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your reply. I did follow your proposal, I mean, to return and print it out the function. There another bet here which is a big surprise to me. Doing like that, it works without any errors but it change completely the output. It print only the first row of the columns 1 and 2 while it should print the whole columns. What am I not understanding still?

Comment: Ah, that is a completely different problem. Your function ends when it _returns_. It only returns one result and you need multiple. The simplest way to achieve that is to return a list of results. In other words, put `results = []` at the beginning of your list, then in the `for` loop, instead of returning, add items to the list by `results.append(...)` and then after the loop `return results`.

Comment: it print only the console output. If I use << with open("pippo.txt", "w") as txt_file: txt_file.write(a) txt_file.close()>>, it say me the same thing: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list"

Comment: Now you no longer have a string, but a list, so you need to iterate through items of your list in a `for` loop and write each of them into the file.

Comment: I am not sure I've understood how to do but I am going to try some codes. For the moment thank you

Comment: Thank you -zvone-, I found how to work it out with your advices. Have a nice day!